# SED not working [unterminated `s' command]

Tags: linux, sed

i am trying to replace content of file using sed by following commands

```
searchString='(<property *name="sourceUrl" *value="\)[^?]*~'
replacementString="file:///tmp/abc-efg"
sed -i 's~\${searchString}\1${replacementString}~g' $file
```

but it is giving

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a separator (which is `~` in your case).  It looks like you are trying to put it on the end of `$searchString`, which is strange.  I don't know why you're doing that.  The reason it doesn't work is because the variables don't get expanded inside single-quoted strings.

This might work:

```
sed -i "s~${searchString}\1${replacementString}~g" $file
```

Really though, it'll be easier to understand like this:

```
~ $ cat foo
<property name="sourceUrl" value="someurl?param=val"></property>
~ $ searchString='\(<property *name="sourceUrl" *value="\)[^?]*'
~ $ replacementString='file:///tmp/abc-efg'
~ $ sed -e "s~${searchString}~\1${replacementString}~g" foo
<property name="sourceUrl" value="file:///tmp/abc-efg?param=val"></property>
```

Comment: 1. it is giving me `sed: -e expression #1, char 43: Invalid back reference` .
2. I am wondering why have you added `\\` in start of `searchString`. thanks :)

Comment: The `\(` is for the start of the backreference.  `\)` is the end of it.  I've updated this answer with a full session so that you can see exactly what works for me.

Answer (score 0):

your command should be:

```
sed -i "s~${searchString}~${replacementString}~g" $file
```

- `~` missing the internal patterne separator
- simple -> double quote for variable substitution

but

- be careful to your 2 string that are treated as regex in sed (so meta character should be escaped or classified

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to replace the `value="..."` parameter and keep the rest?

```
searchString='\(<property *name="sourceUrl" *value="\)[^"]*'
replacementString="file:///tmp/abc-efg"
sed -i "s~$searchString~\\1$replacementString~" "$file"
```

I made the following changes:

- The opening grouping parenthesis requires a backslash (or else the closing parenthesis should also not be backslashed -- this depends on your `sed` dialect)
- The regex to match the `value="..."` field is `[^"]*` instead of `[^?]*` -- I don't know whether a question mark makes sense in your particular scenario, but anything which is not a double quote is usually the safe and robust match (within the dark and murky realm of [using regex for structured data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)).
- Obviously, [fix quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) and add the missing `~` delimiter between the search pattern and the replacement string.  You had it in the search string (which wasn't being interpolated because of the single quotes) but it's a delimiter, not part of the search string, so it makes more sense to put it in the `sed` script itself.
- The search pattern needs to contain one back reference, which is then included in the replacement.
- The `g` flag is superfluous, unless you genuinely expect to find multiple matches per input line.